# Tag excerpts and wikis, should citations be fully addresses?

Tags: discussion

While bringing a note from a website or a book, is it enough to make a link to the website in which the words are borrowed from or it is better to use a separate sentence to mention the citation?

> As mentioned in [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org); this tags is about...

or this way:

> As mentioned in [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org) [ * ]; this tags is about...
>   --- Quoted tag wiki goes here ---
>   [ * ] footnote or citation indicating that the wiki is brought from a website page.

P.S.: Take a look at the tag for [phd](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/phd/info) and [research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/research/info) as examples of this question. Which one is preferred?

Comment: I am not sure we really need quotes in our tag wikis. Can you give an example? Why not just paraphrase the material for our tag wiki?

Comment: @StrongBad take a look at the P.S. I added to the question. Specially in the info of research tag, there is a note and the end.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one

Comment: @StrongBad this question also helps the topic: [Would it be OK to paste content from Wikipedia into a popular empty tag-wiki?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79000/would-it-be-ok-to-paste-content-from-wikipedia-into-a-popular-empty-tag-wiki)

Comment: @StrongBad I read the two pages, I think it is OK to put a direct link to the Wikipedia and block quote a paragraph or less. Am I right? (the same as this tag: [phd](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/phd/info))